# How to test AngularJs global variable using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a scenario where I need to test controller method using Karma Jasmine. Scenario is simple,

Angular code

```
var globalVariable = "startEapplication";    
$scope.myMethod = function(request, response) {
                    if(globalVariable === "startEapplication" && request.customer) {
```

Now, instead of startEapplication I need to pass null for the negative scenario testing. Basically I need to mock the global variable from Karma Jasmine.

Is there anyway to modify the Angular global variable from Karma Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, globalVariable  is not a angular global variable and since it is declared inside controller you will not be able to access from the spec itself.

And if you want to cover the negative scenario I used to follow below approach to test the private variable.

To test the negative scenario, you can declare one separate private object and associate it with scope.

Example :

```
// Add the comment saying this should be only be accessed for unit test puropse
$scope._private_ = {
    globalVariable : "startEapplication"
}
```

Also you need to do the changes the way you are comparing it so that the spec will also point to same object like

```
if($scope._private_.globalVariable === "startEapplication")
```

Now you can mock this global variable inside your spec.